# First_or_initialize and nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, nested-attributes

I've got a `User` model with basically an **email** and a **username**.
I've got a nested `Profile` model that has a **name**, a **position**, and a **description**.

When a `User` is signing up, *everything* (except the description) is **required**. I've got a single form that works perfectly well with this nested model.

[image: Sign Up form]

Now comes **Oauth**: I want to allow visitors to sign up using their GitHub account.
This method ([RailsCast #235](http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-devise-and-omniauth-revised)) allows me to initialize a new `User` and **automatically fill in** 4 `User` attributes: provider, uid, email, and username.

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize do |user|
    user.provider = auth.provider
    user.uid = auth.uid
    user.email = auth.info.email
    user.username = auth.info.nickname
  end
end
```

But what I'd like is also to initialize a nested Profile with the **name**, and eventually the **position**, filled with information from the hash I obtain from GitHub.

I tried putting something like `user.build_profile(:name => auth.info.name)` or `user.profile.name = auth.info.name` but I can't seem to find how to **build** this nested element.

Answer (score 0):

i got this problem solved by do this as below(i use devise and ominauth):
THIS IS THE "RegistrationsController"

```
# GET /resource/sign_up
def new
   resource = build_resource({})
   # check the session exists or not
   if session["devise.user_person_attributes"]
      ### just do anything you need to do prefill the form. this works very well for me
      resource.build_person(gender: session["devise.user_person_attributes"]["gender"]) 
   else
      resource.build_person
   end
   respond_with root_path
end
```

AND FOR THE "OmniauthCallbacksController", I DO THIS:

```
def all
    omniauth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    authentication = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(omniauth['provider'], omniauth['uid'])
    if authentication
        .
        .(SOME CODE OMITTED)
    elsif current_user
        .
        .
        .(SOME CODE OMITTED)
    else
        user = User.from_omniauth(omniauth)
        flash[:notice] = "Please finalize your registration"
        session["devise.user_attributes"] = user.attributes
        session["devise.user_person_attributes"] = user.person.attributes
        session["devise.auth_attributes"] = user.authentications.first.attributes

        redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
end

alias_method :twitter, :all
alias_method :facebook, :all
```

this works cool for me! and i hope this will help other as well.